# Morkdown - why can't I get color themes working?

Tags: themes, markdown

I'm on a Mac running Yosemite.  I installed `Homebrew`, then used `Homebrew` to install `node`.  (`npm` comes with `node`).

I then ran

```
> npm install -g morkdown
```

I now have `which morkdown` returning `/usr/local/bin/morkdown` which is a symbolic link pointing to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/morkdown/bin/morkdown.js`, which is executable.

However, when I launch `morkdown` via:

```
> morkdown great_american_novel.md
```

I get the chrome app launched and the input and output accepting plain text and generating HTML properly, but I get no CSS themes and everything is just blank black on white with no styling whatsoever.

What is the right forum for me to post this question so that I can get timely help?  The GitHub Issues page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be notifying the developers of an issue through [the morkdown Github issues page](https://github.com/rvagg/morkdown/issues).